# Effects of different changes on test statistic

Tags: self-study, t-test, sample-size, sample

Will each of the following increase, decrease, or have no effect on the value of the test statistic in a one-independent sample t-test?

1. The sample size is doubled
2. The level of significance is reduced
3. The sample variance increases
4. The difference between the sample and population mean increased

This was given as part of an assignment and I can't find a set of rules that helps with this question.

Comment: #1 is tough to answer because when the sample size is doubled, who knows what will happen to the mean difference and the variance?  The person who posed that question may implicitly be supposing that you aren't to be thinking about changing these variables operationally, but purely hypothetically in the sense that all other terms are assumed to remain the same.

Comment: @whuber I think it's reasonable to assume that all these questions are intended to be taken as "and nothing else changes".

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an assignment, here's a hint: Look at the formula for the one sample t-test

$$t = \frac{\overline{x} - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}}$$

and think about what each change would do.

Comment: I don't know from the formula. I looked at it and variance, level, of significance, and mean difference aren't in the formula. I'm thinking doubling the sample size would increase the value because, its in the denominator. Other than that I'm stumped and that may not even be right.

Comment: Johnny, $s$ is the square root of the variance and $\bar{x}-\mu_0$ is the mean difference, so both of them *are* in the formula. Indeed, no term in the formula depends on the significance level. What do you suppose that means will happen to $t$ if the significance level is changed?

Comment: Here's what i think

Comment: Doubling the sample size will increase the value of t, (the level of significance I don't understand- still not getting it?), increasing the sample variance will decrease the value of t, and an increase in difference of means will increase the t value.

Comment: Regarding level of significance: If it's not in the formula, changing it won't change anything, right?

Comment: Level of significance is indeed not in the formula, knowing that does tell you which impact it is going to have.

Comment: Increase, no effect, decrease, increase